# Same schema, same data, same execution plan?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, execution-plan

I have a T-SQL stored procedure in SQL Server 2014 SP2 that takes 3x as long on the server as it does from my local environment.

I restored my local database to what was on the server, so schema and data are the same.

I'm a programmer, not really a DBA, so bear with me on this.

The execution plans seem the same until you look at the XML. On my local environment, a Stream Aggregate is used for one of the queries to make a distinct select, while on the server, it looks like a Sort is used with a hash.

It appears that the fact that the server has less processors than my (beast) local machine is contributing to the problem. Every query takes a little longer on the server. Could this be the reason that the sort/hash is chosen on the server instead of the Stream Aggregate?

Is there a way to force the Stream Aggregate?

Here is the SQL for the stored proc: http://pastebin.com/kkXM3Bsf

Here is the execution plan for my local environment: http://pastebin.com/0u7SHxnM

Here is the execution plan for the server: http://pastebin.com/9sE9DfM0

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The hardware configuration can affect plan selection as I discuss in my answer to the related Q & A:

[difference in execution plans on UAT and PROD server](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/53726)

The question doesn't quantify the "3x" performance difference, but assuming it is important enough to be concerned about:

- You can force the broad shape of a plan completely using a [Plan Guide](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190417.aspx) or [`USE PLAN` hint](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186343.aspx). This will prevent the optimizer choosing a different plan shape over time as the data volume and distribution changes, so it is important to review forced plans regularly.
- You can often get closer to the desired plan shape with targeted `FORCESEEK` hints on tables that should be accessed by a seek (e.g. driven by a nested loops join) rather than a scan (with a hash or merge join). In your case, the `FORCESEEK` hint(s) could be applied to `Account` and/or `CustomerLocation`. This may be preferable to forcing the whole plan shape as in the previous point, as it gives the optimizer freedom in other areas of the plan.
- You could give the optimizer a better chance with the `@country is null or ca.Country = @country` predicate by using a `RECOMPILE` hint, or writing two separate queries (one for the `NULL` case; the other for non-`NULL`) surrounded by an `IF @country IS NULL` test. Try the two separate queries first.
- You should be able to avoid the sort spill with a `QUERYTRACEON (7470)` hint. This is documented in:

  [FIX: Sort operator spills to tempdb in SQL Server 2012 or SQL Server 2014 when estimated number of rows and row size are correct](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3088480)
- There is no supported way to force a Stream Aggregate (over a Sort Distinct), without forcing the whole plan.
- You should consider indexing the heap table variable (a PK at least), and/or using a temporary table instead.

I would start by writing the query as two alternatives (or using the `RECOMPILE` hint, if you can tolerate a recompilation on each execution), with the 7470 trace flag enabled, and go from there. Plan forcing would be my least favourite option.

If the server has a very large amount of memory, and plans routinely prefer memory-consuming operators when they should not, you could consider testing *your whole workload* with TF 2335 as in the linked Q & A. I would try the more targeted approaches first.

See also my article: [Parameter Sniffing, Embedding, and the `RECOMPILE` Options](https://sqlperformance.com/2013/08/t-sql-queries/parameter-sniffing-embedding-and-the-recompile-options)