# Huge different execution plan between SQL 2008R2 and SQL 2014

Tags: sql-server

The query is generated by Entity Framework. It take 2 minutes in PROD, less than 1 second in DEV. On row counts of the tables, there are not big difference between PROD and DEV.

PROD: SQL Server 2008R2 Ent SP3, CPU 40, Max RAM 40gb, MaxDOP 4

DEV: SQL 2014 Ent, CPU 4, Max RAM 16gb

The query. I took out the SELECT part, it is too long and not a big issue with my question.

```
exec sp_executesql N'SELECT ...
FROM                      [dbo].[AwsEC2Instance] AS [Extent1]
LEFT OUTER JOIN  (SELECT [Extent2].[ComputerId] AS [ComputerId1], [Extent2].[EntityLastUpdated] AS [EntityLastUpdated1], [Extent2].[AreaOfAuthority] AS [AreaOfAuthority], [Extent2].[BuildId] AS [BuildId], [Extent2].[DomainId] AS [DomainId], [Extent2].[EnvironmentId] AS [EnvironmentId], [Extent2].[HardwareId] AS [HardwareId], [Extent2].[InstallDate] AS [InstallDate], [Extent2].[LocationId] AS [LocationId], [Extent2].[MemoryGBs] AS [MemoryGBs], [Extent2].[ModelId] AS [ModelId], [Extent2].[Name] AS [Name], [Extent2].[NetworkZoneId] AS [NetworkZoneId], [Extent2].[OperatingSystemId] AS [OperatingSystemId], [Extent2].[PowerState] AS [PowerState], [Extent2].[RetirementDate] AS [RetirementDate], [Extent2].[Status] AS [Status], [Extent2].[SupportOrganization] AS [SupportOrganization], [Extent3].[ComputerId] AS [ComputerId14]
    FROM  [dbo].[Computer] AS [Extent2]
    LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[AwsEC2Instance] AS [Extent3] ON [Extent2].[ComputerId] = [Extent3].[ComputerId] ) AS [Join1] ON [Extent1].[ComputerId] = [Join1].[ComputerId14]
LEFT OUTER JOIN  (SELECT [Extent4].[ComputerId] AS [ComputerId2], [Extent4].[EntityLastUpdated] AS [EntityLastUpdated2], [Extent4].[ComputerGraphicsProcessingUnitSettingsId] AS [ComputerGraphicsProcessingUnitSettingsId], [Extent4].[GraphicsProcessingUnitModelId] AS [GraphicsProcessingUnitModelId], [Extent4].[NumberOfProcessors] AS [NumberOfProcessors], [Join3].[ComputerId15], [Join3].[ComputerId16]
    FROM  [dbo].[ComputerGraphicsProcessingUnitSettings] AS [Extent4]
    INNER JOIN  (SELECT [Extent5].[ComputerId] AS [ComputerId15], [Extent6].[ComputerId] AS [ComputerId16]
        FROM  [dbo].[Computer] AS [Extent5]
        LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[AwsEC2Instance] AS [Extent6] ON [Extent5].[ComputerId] = [Extent6].[ComputerId] ) AS [Join3] ON [Extent4].[ComputerId] = [Join3].[ComputerId15] ) AS [Join4] ON [Extent1].[ComputerId] = [Join4].[ComputerId16]
LEFT OUTER JOIN  (SELECT [Extent7].[ComputerId] AS [ComputerId3], [Extent7].[EntityLastUpdated] AS [EntityLastUpdated3], [Extent7].[ComputerDiscoveryDetailId] AS [ComputerDiscoveryDetailId], [Extent7].[LastHostInfoScanDate] AS [LastHostInfoScanDate], [Extent7].[LastRebootDate] AS [LastRebootDate], [Extent7].[ScannerName] AS [ScannerName], [Join6].[ComputerId17], [Join6].[ComputerId18]
    FROM  [dbo].[ComputerDiscoveryDetail] AS [Extent7]
    INNER JOIN  (SELECT [Extent8].[ComputerId] AS [ComputerId17], [Extent9].[ComputerId] AS [ComputerId18]
        FROM  [dbo].[Computer] AS [Extent8]
        LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[AwsEC2Instance] AS [Extent9] ON [Extent8].[ComputerId] = [Extent9].[ComputerId] ) AS [Join6] ON [Extent7].[ComputerId] = [Join6].[ComputerId17] ) AS [Join7] ON [Extent1].[ComputerId] = [Join7].[ComputerId18]
LEFT OUTER JOIN  (SELECT [Extent10].[ComputerId] AS [ComputerId4], [Extent10].[EntityLastUpdated] AS [EntityLastUpdated4], [Extent10].[ComputerActiveDirectorySettingsId] AS [ComputerActiveDirectorySettingsId], [Extent10].[DistinguishedName] AS [DistinguishedName], [Extent10].[DnsHostName] AS [DnsHostName], [Extent10].[IsAccountDisabled] AS [IsAccountDisabled], [Extent10].[LastLogon] AS [LastLogon], [Extent10].[LastLogonTimestamp] AS [LastLogonTimestamp], [Extent10].[ObjectGuid] AS [ObjectGuid], [Extent10].[OperatingSystem] AS [OperatingSystem], [Extent10].[PasswordLastSet] AS [PasswordLastSet], [Extent10].[Path] AS [Path], [Extent10].[SamAccountName] AS [SamAccountName], [Extent10].[ServicePack] AS [ServicePack], [Extent10].[Sid] AS [Sid], [Extent10].[WhenCreated] AS [WhenCreated], [Join9].[ComputerId19], [Join9].[ComputerId20]
    FROM  [dbo].[ComputerActiveDirectorySettings] AS [Extent10]
    INNER JOIN  (SELECT [Extent11].[ComputerId] AS [ComputerId19], [Extent12].[ComputerId] AS [ComputerId20]
        FROM  [dbo].[Computer] AS [Extent11]
        LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[AwsEC2Instance] AS [Extent12] ON [Extent11].[ComputerId] = [Extent12].[ComputerId] ) AS [Join9] ON [Extent10].[ComputerId] = [Join9].[ComputerId19] ) AS [Join10] ON [Extent1].[ComputerId] = [Join10].[ComputerId20]
LEFT OUTER JOIN  (SELECT [Extent13].[ComputerId] AS [ComputerId5], [Extent13].[EntityLastUpdated] AS [EntityLastUpdated5], [Extent13].[ComputerVirtualizationHostSettingsId] AS [ComputerVirtualizationHostSettingsId], [Extent13].[VirtualizationClusterId] AS [VirtualizationClusterId], [Join12].[ComputerId21], [Join12].[ComputerId22]
    FROM  [dbo].[ComputerVirtualizationHostSettings] AS [Extent13]
    INNER JOIN  (SELECT [Extent14].[ComputerId] AS [ComputerId21], [Extent15].[ComputerId] AS [ComputerId22]
        FROM  [dbo].[Computer] AS [Extent14]
        LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[AwsEC2Instance] AS [Extent15] ON [Extent14].[ComputerId] = [Extent15].[ComputerId] ) AS [Join12] ON [Extent13].[ComputerId] = [Join12].[ComputerId21] ) AS [Join13] ON [Extent1].[ComputerId] = [Join13].[ComputerId22]
LEFT OUTER JOIN  (SELECT [Extent16].[ComputerId] AS [ComputerId6], [Extent16].[EntityLastUpdated] AS [EntityLastUpdated6], [Extent16].[ComputerNetworkSettingsId] AS [ComputerNetworkSettingsId], [Extent16].[DnsDomain] AS [DnsDomain], [Extent16].[DnsHostName] AS [DnsHostName], [Join15].[ComputerId23], [Join15].[ComputerId24]
    FROM  [dbo].[ComputerNetworkSettings] AS [Extent16]
    INNER JOIN  (SELECT [Extent17].[ComputerId] AS [ComputerId23], [Extent18].[ComputerId] AS [ComputerId24]
        FROM  [dbo].[Computer] AS [Extent17]
        LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[AwsEC2Instance] AS [Extent18] ON [Extent17].[ComputerId] = [Extent18].[ComputerId] ) AS [Join15] ON [Extent16].[ComputerId] = [Join15].[ComputerId23] ) AS [Join16] ON [Extent1].[ComputerId] = [Join16].[ComputerId24]
LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[ComputerHardware] AS [Extent19] ON [Join1].[HardwareId] = [Extent19].[ComputerHardwareId]
LEFT OUTER JOIN  (SELECT [Extent20].[ComputerId] AS [ComputerId7], [Extent20].[EntityLastUpdated] AS [EntityLastUpdated7], [Extent20].[CapacityManagedBy] AS [CapacityManagedBy], [Extent20].[ComputerJAPSettingsId] AS [ComputerJAPSettingsId], [Extent20].[ServerPool] AS [ServerPool], [Extent20].[ServerUsage] AS [ServerUsage], [Extent20].[Track] AS [Track], [Extent20].[Usage] AS [Usage], [Extent20].[Version] AS [Version], [Join19].[ComputerId25], [Join19].[ComputerId26]
    FROM  [dbo].[ComputerJAPSettings] AS [Extent20]
    INNER JOIN  (SELECT [Extent21].[ComputerId] AS [ComputerId25], [Extent22].[ComputerId] AS [ComputerId26]
        FROM  [dbo].[Computer] AS [Extent21]
        LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[AwsEC2Instance] AS [Extent22] ON [Extent21].[ComputerId] = [Extent22].[ComputerId] ) AS [Join19] ON [Extent20].[ComputerId] = [Join19].[ComputerId25] ) AS [Join20] ON [Extent1].[ComputerId] = [Join20].[ComputerId26]
LEFT OUTER JOIN  (SELECT [Extent23].[ComputerId] AS [ComputerId8], [Extent23].[EntityLastUpdated] AS [EntityLastUpdated8], [Extent23].[ComputerProvisioningDetailsId] AS [ComputerProvisioningDetailsId], [Extent23].[Division] AS [Division], [Extent23].[NumberOfNetworkAdapters] AS [NumberOfNetworkAdapters], [Extent23].[PlannedActivity] AS [PlannedActivity], [Extent23].[PrimaryIPAddress] AS [PrimaryIPAddress], [Extent23].[PrimaryMacAddress] AS [PrimaryMacAddress], [Extent23].[RequestItem] AS [RequestItem], [Extent23].[RequestNumber] AS [RequestNumber], [Join22].[ComputerId27], [Join22].[ComputerId28]
    FROM  [dbo].[ComputerProvisioningDetails] AS [Extent23]
    INNER JOIN  (SELECT [Extent24].[ComputerId] AS [ComputerId27], [Extent25].[ComputerId] AS [ComputerId28]
        FROM  [dbo].[Computer] AS [Extent24]
        LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[AwsEC2Instance] AS [Extent25] ON [Extent24].[ComputerId] = [Extent25].[ComputerId] ) AS [Join22] ON [Extent23].[ComputerId] = [Join22].[ComputerId27] ) AS [Join23] ON [Extent1].[ComputerId] = [Join23].[ComputerId28]
LEFT OUTER JOIN  (SELECT [Extent26].[ComputerId] AS [ComputerId9], [Extent26].[EntityLastUpdated] AS [EntityLastUpdated9], [Extent26].[CentralProcessingUnitModelId] AS [CentralProcessingUnitModelId], [Extent26].[ComputerCentralProcessingUnitSettingsId] AS [ComputerCentralProcessingUnitSettingsId], [Extent26].[NumberOfLogicalProcessors] AS [NumberOfLogicalProcessors], [Extent26].[NumberOfProcessors] AS [NumberOfProcessors], [Join25].[ComputerId29], [Join25].[ComputerId30]
    FROM  [dbo].[ComputerCentralProcessingUnitSettings] AS [Extent26]
    INNER JOIN  (SELECT [Extent27].[ComputerId] AS [ComputerId29], [Extent28].[ComputerId] AS [ComputerId30]
        FROM  [dbo].[Computer] AS [Extent27]
        LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[AwsEC2Instance] AS [Extent28] ON [Extent27].[ComputerId] = [Extent28].[ComputerId] ) AS [Join25] ON [Extent26].[ComputerId] = [Join25].[ComputerId29] ) AS [Join26] ON [Extent1].[ComputerId] = [Join26].[ComputerId30]
LEFT OUTER JOIN  (SELECT [Extent29].[ComputerId] AS [ComputerId10], [Extent29].[EntityLastUpdated] AS [EntityLastUpdated10], [Extent29].[BackupExclusionRFC] AS [BackupExclusionRFC], [Extent29].[BackupInclusionRFC] AS [BackupInclusionRFC], [Extent29].[BackupMethod] AS [BackupMethod], [Extent29].[BackupType] AS [BackupType], [Extent29].[ComputerBackupSettingsId] AS [ComputerBackupSettingsId], [Extent29].[InterfaceId] AS [InterfaceId], [Extent29].[IsBackupMediaServer] AS [IsBackupMediaServer], [Extent29].[RetentionPeriod] AS [RetentionPeriod], [Extent29].[Status] AS [Status1], [Join28].[ComputerId31], [Join28].[ComputerId32]
    FROM  [dbo].[ComputerBackupSettings] AS [Extent29]
    INNER JOIN  (SELECT [Extent30].[ComputerId] AS [ComputerId31], [Extent31].[ComputerId] AS [ComputerId32]
        FROM  [dbo].[Computer] AS [Extent30]
        LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[AwsEC2Instance] AS [Extent31] ON [Extent30].[ComputerId] = [Extent31].[ComputerId] ) AS [Join28] ON [Extent29].[ComputerId] = [Join28].[ComputerId31] ) AS [Join29] ON [Extent1].[ComputerId] = [Join29].[ComputerId32]
LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[ComputerDomain] AS [Extent32] ON [Join1].[DomainId] = [Extent32].[ComputerDomainId]
LEFT OUTER JOIN  (SELECT [Extent33].[ComputerId] AS [ComputerId11], [Extent33].[EntityLastUpdated] AS [EntityLastUpdated11], [Extent33].[ComputerMonitoringSettingsId] AS [ComputerMonitoringSettingsId], [Extent33].[IPAddressId] AS [IPAddressId], [Extent33].[IsExcludedFromBpm] AS [IsExcludedFromBpm], [Extent33].[MonitoringExclusionRFC] AS [MonitoringExclusionRFC], [Extent33].[Profile] AS [Profile], [Join32].[ComputerId33], [Join32].[ComputerId34]
    FROM  [dbo].[ComputerMonitoringSettings] AS [Extent33]
    INNER JOIN  (SELECT [Extent34].[ComputerId] AS [ComputerId33], [Extent35].[ComputerId] AS [ComputerId34]
        FROM  [dbo].[Computer] AS [Extent34]
        LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[AwsEC2Instance] AS [Extent35] ON [Extent34].[ComputerId] = [Extent35].[ComputerId] ) AS [Join32] ON [Extent33].[ComputerId] = [Join32].[ComputerId33] ) AS [Join33] ON [Extent1].[ComputerId] = [Join33].[ComputerId34]
LEFT OUTER JOIN  (SELECT [Extent36].[ComputerId] AS [ComputerId12], [Extent36].[EntityLastUpdated] AS [EntityLastUpdated12], [Extent36].[ComputerDisasterRecoverySettingsId] AS [ComputerDisasterRecoverySettingsId], [Extent36].[Setup] AS [Setup], [Extent36].[Usage] AS [Usage], [Join35].[ComputerId35], [Join35].[ComputerId36]
    FROM  [dbo].[ComputerDisasterRecoverySettings] AS [Extent36]
    INNER JOIN  (SELECT [Extent37].[ComputerId] AS [ComputerId35], [Extent38].[ComputerId] AS [ComputerId36]
        FROM  [dbo].[Computer] AS [Extent37]
        LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[AwsEC2Instance] AS [Extent38] ON [Extent37].[ComputerId] = [Extent38].[ComputerId] ) AS [Join35] ON [Extent36].[ComputerId] = [Join35].[ComputerId35] ) AS [Join36] ON [Extent1].[ComputerId] = [Join36].[ComputerId36]
LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[ComputeBuildRelease] AS [Extent39] ON [Join1].[BuildId] = [Extent39].[ComputeBuildReleaseId]
LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[NetworkZone] AS [Extent40] ON [Join1].[NetworkZoneId] = [Extent40].[NetworkZoneId]
LEFT OUTER JOIN  (SELECT [Extent41].[ComputerId] AS [ComputerId13], [Extent41].[EntityLastUpdated] AS [EntityLastUpdated13], [Extent41].[ComputerVirtualMachineSettingsId] AS [ComputerVirtualMachineSettingsId], [Extent41].[IdentifyingNumber] AS [IdentifyingNumber], [Extent41].[LeaseEndDate] AS [LeaseEndDate], [Extent41].[LeaseType] AS [LeaseType], [Extent41].[PerformanceTier] AS [PerformanceTier], [Extent41].[PhysicalHostId] AS [PhysicalHostId], [Extent41].[Pool] AS [Pool], [Extent41].[VirtualizationClusterId] AS [VirtualizationClusterId], [Join40].[ComputerId37], [Join40].[ComputerId38]
    FROM  [dbo].[ComputerVirtualMachineSettings] AS [Extent41]
    INNER JOIN  (SELECT [Extent42].[ComputerId] AS [ComputerId37], [Extent43].[ComputerId] AS [ComputerId38]
        FROM  [dbo].[Computer] AS [Extent42]
        LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[AwsEC2Instance] AS [Extent43] ON [Extent42].[ComputerId] = [Extent43].[ComputerId] ) AS [Join40] ON [Extent41].[ComputerId] = [Join40].[ComputerId37] ) AS [Join41] ON [Extent1].[ComputerId] = [Join41].[ComputerId38]
LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[Environment] AS [Extent44] ON [Join1].[EnvironmentId] = [Extent44].[EnvironmentId]
LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[ComputerOperatingSystem] AS [Extent45] ON [Join1].[OperatingSystemId] = [Extent45].[ComputerOperatingSystemId]
LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[ComputerModel] AS [Extent46] ON [Join1].[ModelId] = [Extent46].[ComputerModelId]
LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[Location] AS [Extent47] ON [Join1].[LocationId] = [Extent47].[LocationId]
WHERE [Extent1].[AwsEC2InstanceId] = @p__linq__0',N'@p__linq__0 uniqueidentifier',@p__linq__0='01875F53-704D-E811-80E5-0200003F9F37'
```

Due to execution plan exceeding 2mb, it cannot be pasted on BrentOzar's website.

In PROD execution plan, several hash matches cost a lot. It takes 2 minutes to run.
[image]

In Dev execution plan, no hash match. It takes 1 second to run.
[image]

My question is why so much different execution plan? Any chance it can finish in PROD less than 90 second?

If the query could be rewritten by human, all the subqueries can disappear and changed to simple left join, it runs very fast.

Comment: The optimizer changed from 2008 to 2012 and again in 2014. You should not expect a 1:1 when testing in your dev environment to your prod environment. I believe you can put your dev environment down to a different compatibility level and adjust it to run as the old engine though.

Comment: In addition to @Shaulinator You said there aren't any big difference on row counts in prod and dev, but what is the difference? Index differences? Updated statistics in both environments? Can you do a back up and restore to dev to make them a wee bit closer?

Comment: [Ed Pollack from SQL Shack explaining the optimizer](https://www.sqlshack.com/query-optimizer-changes-in-sql-server-2016-explained/)

Comment: You can always post the XML on pastebin to share.

Comment: @sp_BlitzErik, pastebin is blocked by my company. Thanks.

Comment: since you have [difference in memory - see my question and answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/55254/8783).

Comment: Your company blocks pastebin but not stack exchange? Can you upload the XML file ***anywhere?*** I mean, it's just a file, right? OneDrive, DropBox, Google, SharePoint, WordPress, any FTP location, MySpace...

Comment: @Kin, tested with T2335. It still runs 2 minutes.

Comment: You might do a sanity check to make sure stats are up-to-date and prod has the same non-clustered indexes as dev.

Comment: @Wendy - how about TF 9481 just to rule out the new CE affecting the plan ?

Comment: @AaronBertrand, I tried upload to answers.sql performance, not successful.

Comment: how about you just create a secret gist and upload to github - this is permitted everywhere :-)

Comment: So you have 2 sql dbs with different specs, versions, data and probably indexes/stats and one goes faster than the other. But what is the real problem you are trying to solve? Im guessing that prod is too slow. So lets focus on that.

Comment: For the tables queried, do they both have the same definition and indexes in both dev and prod? Are your statistics and indexes healthy and maintained regularly?