# Scan on trigger Seek on SSMS

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, trigger

I'm having a performance issue with a trigger when insert/delete on a table, it scan an index associated to a view, but if I execute the update manually it generate a seek.

I updated statistics for the view and SubscriberXList table but it keeps doing the scan. Also recompile ... restart the engine (it's a test environment) ... pray to God :p

**Tables**:

Subscriber

SubscriberXList (N to N relationship between Subscribers and List)

SubscribersAmountByList (indexed view)

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[SubscriberXList] (
    [IdList] INT      NOT NULL,
    [IdSubscriber]      INT      NOT NULL,
    [Active]            BIT      NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_SubscriberXList] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([IdList] ASC, [IdSubscriber] ASC),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_SubscriberXList_Suscriber] FOREIGN KEY ([IdSubscriber]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Subscriber] ([IdSubscriber]),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_SubscriberXList_List] FOREIGN KEY ([IdList]) REFERENCES [dbo].[List] ([IdList]) ON DELETE CASCADE
);
GO
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_SubscriberXList_IdSubscriber]
    ON [dbo].[SubscriberXList]([IdSubscriber] ASC)
    INCLUDE([IdList], [Active]);
GO

CREATE VIEW [dbo].[vw_SubscribersAmountByList]  WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS
SELECT 
    [sxl].IdList,
    COUNT_BIG(*) AS Amount
    FROM  [dbo].[SubscriberXList] AS [sxl] 
    INNER JOIN [dbo].[Subscriber] AS [s]  ON [sxl].[IdSubscriber] = [s].[IdSubscriber]
    WHERE (1 = [sxl].[Active]) AND (1 = [s].[Status] OR 2 = [s].[Status])
    GROUP BY [sxl].IdList
GO
CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX [CI_SubscribersAmountByList]
    ON [dbo].[SubscribersAmountByList]([IdList] ASC);
```

The query that generate the scan belongs to a trigger on SubscriberXList insert and delete. At the end of the trigger has an update that generate a scan when need to update a view related to SubscriberXList and Subscriber.

```
CREATE TRIGGER dbo.T_SubscriberxList_I
ON dbo.SubscriberXList
AFTER INSERT
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @Subscribers TABLE (IdSubscriber INT PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED, Total INT)
    DECLARE @TotalSubscribers INT


    UPDATE dbo.SubscriberXListAmount
    SET Amount = Amount + Total
    OUTPUT inserted.IdSubscriber, inserted.Amount INTO @Subscribers
    FROM dbo.SubscriberXListAmount SXLA
    JOIN (SELECT IdSubscriber, COUNT(1) Total
        FROM INSERTED I
        INNER JOIN dbo.List SL on SL.IdList = I.IdList
        WHERE SL.IsSegment = 0 AND SL.Active = 1 AND SL.Visible = 1
        GROUP BY I.IdSubscriber) s on s.IdSubscriber = SXLA.IdSubscriber

    SET @TotalSubscribers = @@ROWCOUNT;

    DELETE FROM @Subscribers
    FROM @Subscribers s
    JOIN dbo.Subscriber  s2 ON s2.IdSubscriber = s.IdSubscriber
    WHERE S2.IdSubscribersStatus <> 2

    SET @TotalSubscribers = @TotalSubscribers - @@ROWCOUNT;

    IF @TotalSubscribers > 0
    BEGIN
        declare @query nvarchar(max) = 'DECLARE @Subscribers TABLE (IdSubscriber INT PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED)'

        SELECT @query = @query + '
        INSERT INTO @Subscribers (IdSubscriber) VALUES ('+ CONVERT(varchar,IdSubscriber) + ')'
        FROM @Subscribers

        SET @Query = @query + '
        UPDATE dbo.Subscriber
        SET IdSubscribersStatus = 1
        FROM @Subscribers s2 
        JOIN dbo.Subscriber s ON s2.IdSubscriber = s.IdSubscriber
        OPTION(force order, fast '+convert(varchar,@totalSubscribers)+')';
        EXEC (@query)
    END
END
GO
```

Execution plan when trigger is fired
https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=r1mEYGNEB

Execution plan for manually execution of the update
https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=B11hKM4EB

This happen when calculate the new value for the indexed view.

Also on the execution plan it recommends a new index

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [<Name of Missing Index, sysname,>]
ON [dbo].[SubscriberXList] ([Active])
INCLUDE ([IdList],[IdSubscriber])
```

This index it is a bad index because the SubscriberXList table has the 80% rows with Active = 1 and it's one of the biggest tables on my DB.

I tried with a dynamic query setting the amount of rows to be updated on "Option (fast '+convert(varchar,@AmountSubscribersToUpdate)+')" but keep generating the scan.

What lead to change the execution plan between trigger and manually on ssms??

Thanks!

Comment: You may want to add the trigger definition and the resulting query plan xml (like at pastetheplan.com) for faster answers.

Comment: That execution plans are of which query?

Comment: Thanks Erik for the comment, there are the execution plans.

Comment: Denis, first execution plan (scan) is when the update is executed and need to update a view. second Execution plan is when execute the same update manually and generate a seek.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This isn't really an "apples to apples" comparison.  The trigger version of the query looks like this:

```
UPDATE dbo.Subscriber
SET IdSubscribersStatus = 1
FROM @Subscribers s2 
JOIN dbo.Subscriber s ON s2.IdSubscriber = s.IdSubscriber
OPTION(force order, fast 1)
```

And the manual version of the query looks like this:

```
update dbo.Subscriber
set IdSubscribersStatus = 2
FROM dbo.subscriber s
JOIN @SUbscriber S2 on s2.IdSubscriber = s.IdSubscriber
```

In the trigger version, the join order is being forced, and the written order of the tables has been reversed from the manual update.  Since the fast plan doesn't have the `FORCE ORDER` hint, I would suggest removing that, and reversing the table names in the trigger to match your manual update query.

You may also benefit from putting `OPTION (RECOMPILE)` on the `UPDATE` statement, so that SQL Server has an accurate picture of how many rows are in the table variable.

---

For completeness, there are some other differences in the execution plans:

- Fast plan was on a much new version of SQL Server 2014.

  - Fast: SP3 CU2
  - Slow: SP1+GDR
- Fast plan had more memory available, which [affects the optimizer's plan choices](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/54002/6141)

  - Fast: `EstimatedAvailableMemoryGrant="583270" EstimatedPagesCached="583270"`
  - Slow: `EstimatedAvailableMemoryGrant="307200" EstimatedPagesCached="153600"`
- Fast plan was on a server with more cores available for parallelism

  - Fast: `EstimatedAvailableDegreeOfParallelism="8"`
  - Slow: `EstimatedAvailableDegreeOfParallelism="4"`

Comment: Thanks Josh! I feel stupid. I closed all tabs so I don't know the connection for each test, but surely is as you said. I didin't realize how may updates left on my testing enviroment, so I will run some test I keep attention to this differences you pointed out

Comment: @MarianoG Glad I could I help!  Don't beat yourself up about it.  Good luck in your testing!